# DevExpress databinding - how does it work?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have a LookUpEdit control bound to Race record. It has look-up datasource of Car records and I'm trying to set Race.CarId to the first record in Cars datasource on my form initialization, but I cannot achive it in any ways.

```
// leCallsign is a lookup editor.
// setting datasource - an array of cars
leCallsign.Properties.DataSource = bsCar;
leCallsign.Properties.ForceInitialize();
leCallsign.Properties.ValueMember = "Id";
leCallsign.Properties.DisplayMember = "Callsign";
// bind Race's CarId to datasource's Id
leCallsign.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", bsRace, "CarId", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
// set editor value as the first of cars Id. 
// Because of binding above it hopefully shold update the underlying bsRace record...
leCallsign.EditValue = ((Car)bsCar[0]).Id;
// but it does not neither here
leCallsign.DoValidate();
leCallsign.ResetBindings();
bsRace.ResetBindings(false);
// nor after any of the lines above
```

I tried both with DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged and DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has disappeared as I moved the code from form constructor to Load() event handler.